# Memcache'ing versus database field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

In general, is it better to use something like memcache or the database to store the value for a property of a model that is regularly (ish) recalculated?

Here's my scenario...

I have a load of users, each of which has a property called "score.

A score is the total of the last 10 (ordered by date) instances of a game (there's actually an extra model relation here - a "through" model - but that just complicates this description).

I need to display the user's position (based on their score) on the page, which is calculated by seeing where their score lies in the list of scores of all the users.

This huge calculation of getting every single user's score and finding the current user's position within that list is obviously quite a long process so what's the best way of speeding it up?

Is it better to use memcache and cache each player's score (which will only be updated once a week) or would I be better adding an actual database field for each user which contains their current score?

Or is there another (better) way?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the characteristics of your server load. How many users, how often calculations need to run, how much calculations take memory and storage space. Unless you know answers to these questions, just stick with a database field, but make access to it to have an API, so that you can migrate to different score storage backend if needed.

Also instead of memcached it is better to use a persistent cache like Redis. It has all the characteristics of memcached, but can survive the server restart, so you do not have to run all (heavy) calculations on the server reboot, increasing your downtime.

Comment: So you think it might make sense to add a database field for each user which is simply the result of a calculation made on other available database fields?

It just seems to me that that is duplication of data. The value of score will be available by calculating it OR via the database field.

But maybe that's fine?

Comment: I don't think anything because I don't have the required insight of what you are doing. It depends if your performance characteristics. For this operation, do you prefer CPU performance or memory consumption.